# How can I add some elements to a stack created from a class that has certain methods

Tags: java

So I was given the following GradedActivity class:

```
 public class GradedActivity   
 {   
private double score;  // Numeric score   

public void setScore(double s)
{
    if (s < 0)
    score = 0.0;
else if (s > 100)
    score = 100.0;
    else
        score = s;
 }

public double getScore()
{
   return score;
}


   public char getGrade()
  {   
     char letterGrade;  

  if (score >= 90)
     letterGrade = 'A';
  else if (score >= 80)
     letterGrade = 'B';
  else if (score >= 70)
     letterGrade = 'C';
  else if (score >= 60)
     letterGrade = 'D';
  else
     letterGrade = 'F';

  return letterGrade;
} }
```

and I was tasked with generating a constructor that accepts values for points Obtaned and pointsTotal as arguments, initializes them, and sets the corresponding score (points obtained divided by points total), accessors and mutators for pointsobtained and total.

So here is what I came up with:

```
public class ProgrammingAssignment extends GradedActivity 
{
   public int pointsObtained;
   public int pointsTotal;

   public ProgrammingAssignment(int p, int t)
   {

      pointsObtained = p;
      pointsTotal = t;
   } 

   public int getPointsObtained()
   {
      return pointsObtained;
   }

   public int getPointsTotal()
   {
      return pointsTotal;
   }

   public double getScore()
   {
     return pointsObtained / pointsTotal;
   }

   public void setPointsObtained(int p)
   {
  pointsObtained = p;
}

 public void setPointsTotal(int t)
 {
    pointsTotal = t;
 }     
 }
```

Everything compiles without error, but getScore isn't computing obtained/total (it comes back 0) in my test class:

```
 public class PADemo
 {
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        ProgrammingAssignment p1 = new ProgrammingAssignment(28,30);
            GradedActivity p2 = new ProgrammingAssignment(0,30);

      System.out.println (p1.getPointsObtained());
      System.out.println (p1.getPointsTotal());
      System.out.println (p1.getScore());  
      System.out.println (p1.getGrade());  

      System.out.println (p2.getScore());  
      System.out.println (p2.getGrade());  

      p1.setPointsObtained(25);
      p1.setPointsTotal(40);
      System.out.println (p1.getScore());  
      System.out.println (p1.getGrade() == 'F');  
 }
 }
```

How do I obtain the score (points obtained/points total) with getScore()

Test class returns:

28
30
0.0
F
0.0
F
0.0
true

Comment: You need to implement `StackInt` interface and write your own Stack and then do all the insertion and removal.

Comment: @ScubaSam Please [edit] your question to include the original assignment/homework you have to do. It is not clear what you are trying to do. It looks like you are supposed to implement the `StackInt` interface in a new class, but you tried to use it for something else.

Comment: @ScubaSam What you are saying isn't clear because `stackInt` is an interface, not a class as you said. You need a class which implements that interface. It *might* look like your assignment/homework wants you to do exactly that, but we are not sure. Please [edit] your question to include the original assignment/homework given to you, so we can see what you are supposed to do. It might clear thinks up.

Comment: That's two excerpts from what sounds like a set of instructions. How about you include the actual instructions in your question?

Comment: Sounds like you need to keep track of how many items you've added to the stack in a variable.

Comment: @ScubaSam OK. I've posted it in an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can keep track of how many items you have added, in a variable called `numAdded`. Every time you add something to your collections, you increase `numAdded` by 1.

```java
public class Bull {

    Queue<String> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    StackInt<String> stack = new LinkedStack<>();
    int numAdded = 0;

    public boolean addSomeStuff(String stuff) {
        boolean added = false;
        if (numAdded < 8) {
            stack.push(stuff);
            added = true;
        } else if (queue.size() < 6) {
            added = queue.add(stuff);
        }
        if (added) {
            ++numAdded;
        }
        return added;
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but it was just missing one thing: making the queue have a max of 6

Comment: @ScubaSam OK. I've added that. If there are 6 items in the queue, it won't add any more.

Answer (score 0):

`StackInt` is an `Interface` so `Methods` in that Interface will be Abstract methods.
And when a method is `Abstract` it doesn't have a body for it.
So in order to use methods of `Interface` We need to Override all the `methods` of the interface. And to do so we implement an Interface like

```
class Bullcrap implements StackInt
```

**Note**
On implementation of an interface, you must override all of its methods i.e

```
    E push(E obj);
    E peek();
    E pop();
    boolean empty();
```

All these methods Which belong to `StackInt` should be provided body in `Bullcrap`

```
class Bullcrap implements StackInt  {
    LinkedList<Object> queue = new LinkedList<>();
    Stack<Object> st = new Stack<>();
    @Override
    public Object push(Object obj) {
        if(st.size() < 7) {
            st.push(obj);
            return st;
        }else if(queue.size() < 6) {
            queue.add(obj);
            return queue;
        }
            return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object peek() {
        if(st.size() > 0 ) {
            return st.peek();
        }else if(queue.size() > 0) {
            return queue.getFirst();
        }
            return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public Object pop() {
        if(st.size() > 0) {
            return st.pop();
        }else if(queue.size() > 0) {
            return queue.removeFirst();
        }
            return null;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean empty() {
        return st.isEmpty();
    }
    
}
```

Main Method:

```
       public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception{
            StackInt<Integer> stack = new Bullcrap();
            System.out.println("is Empty? : "+stack.empty());
            for(int i = 1 ; i < 15 ;i++) {
                System.out.println(stack.push(i));
            }
            System.out.println("Is empty ? : "+stack.empty());
            System.out.println("Now POP:");
            
            for(int i = 1 ; i < 15 ; i++) {
                if(i==8){
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("Stack Data Ended: Now Queue");
                }
                if(i <= 7) {
                    System.out.print(stack.pop()+", ");
                }else {
                    System.out.print(stack.pop()+", ");
                }
            }
        }// end of main
```

Output:

```
is Empty? : true
[1]
[1, 2]
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
[8]
[8, 9]
[8, 9, 10]
[8, 9, 10, 11]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
[8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
null
Is empty ? : false
Now POP:
7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 
Stack Data Ended: Now Queue
8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, null,
```

Comment: No, I'm not trying to rewrite or override stackInt

Comment: Then what are you.. Could you be more specific

Comment: I'm trying to add elements to the stack object created from stackInt within the addSomeStuff method within the given parameters

Comment: if it had a size method, it would be very simply, but unfortunately I need to work around it just for processing things that are added to it.

Comment: Maintain a global variable for `StackInt` size.

Comment: can you elaborate?

Comment: @ScubaSam Sure, your method  `public boolean addSomeStuff(String stuff)` adds one more parameter of `int size` where `int size` scope will be global. doing this your addSomeStuff will look like  `public boolean addSomeStuff(String stuff, int size)` and then every time you push an element into `StaclInt` you increase the `size` by 1.

Comment: I get the logic (somewhat), but I'm not sure how to follow through with that exactly. Something like: addSomeStuff(String stuff, int size){ addSomeStuff(stuff); //Everytime something is added, size++; if(size > 7) queue.add(stuff)

Comment: @ScubaSam Yup just like that keep count of how many elements you have added and when you pop remember to decrement the `size` variable too.